# Advanced data import from Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

currently I'm trying to import data from one excel sheet to another.
I'm going through the cells in 13 columns and if value in one of them exceeds X I need to copy this and 719 following rows into another excel sheet.

Does anyone have tips how to do so?
I'm not really into that but I'm trying to simplify work of my service engineers...
Thanks so much for your answers.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to play with MATCH function but values are not in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. Checking maximum value in a row
2. With function "delete row based on cell value" I'm deleting all rows where maximum value is smaller than desired
3. I'm transferring next 720 rows to another sheet with simple addressing

Not as perfect as I'd imagine but is working